# Frame by frame button animation

Tags: android

I have added a frame by frame animation for a button background. When the button is pressed, the animation is started, and when it's finished, another activity is started. The animation is simulating drawing a circle on the button, and the first frame is transparent.

The problem is that when I'm coming back to the first activity, the button will have the last animation frame as the background (the whole circle). I tried to set a transparent frame as the last frame from the list. But in this case, the circle will disappear before the next activity is launched.

Is there an easy way to have the last frame before launching the next activity, and then, when the user get back to the first activity, to have the animation at the first frame?

Answer (score 0):

In the activities onResume() method find the button by ID and then reset the button's background to the animation, or try the clearAnimation() method of the button (I assume this sets the animation back to 0 rather than removing it?). Something like:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
 super.onResume();
 Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.android_button);
 // Clear anitmation
 mButton.getAnimation().reset();
}
```

Comment: I've tried that, but it's not working. When I come back, the last animation frame is drawn.

Comment: Try completely resetting the background in a similar fashion?

Comment: The peoblem is that I'm using the same animation to the rows of a listview. And it's harder to reset the animation for each row.

Comment: Updated my answer try: getAnimation().reset(); on the button.

Comment: Using getAnimation() returns null. I have to use getBackground in order to get the AnimationDrawable object. And this one doesn't have a reset() method.

Comment: Would it be possible to post some of your code? Particularly where you create you views to start with and when you are trying to reset the animation? Might help, I suspect you are accessing the wrong view.